# R Data wrangling questions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling, feature-engineering

I have this sheep.df dataset from dmm package. I need to convert the data format like that:

original data:

1. 2a4242 9a4003 9a4123 1984    T   M 4.4 19.2  40

New format:

- 1 2a4242 9a4003 9a4123 1984    T   M 4.4
- 2 2a4242 9a4003 9a4123 1984    T   M19.2
- 3 2a4242 9a4003 9a4123 1984    T   M 40

So for each of the last 3 columns there will be new rows numbered like 1 2 3 .

Comment: Try `tidyr::pivot_longer()`

Comment: In general, it's helpful to share your data in a reproducible way so that we can load your data (or fake data with same structural properties) on our computers. It's often easiest to do this using the `dput()` function in R, which produces a "recipe" in code to generate an object from scratch. For instance, you could use `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`, include the output in your question, and then we could generate the first few rows of your data exactly as you have them.  (Granted, you noted the source, but most will not have the `dmm` package installed.). btw `sheep.df %>% pivot_longer(Cww:Bwt)`